# Lotus Notes Deployment

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

How do I replace the currently displayed form on Lotus Notes Client into a new created one?

Here's my plan steps:

1. Backup the current form, assuming its name is "Form1". Rename it to "Form1 - Backup"
2. Copy and paste the new form from test to prod, its name is also "Form1".

Do the new form will display automatically? or do I need to Publish it as shown on the picture below?
[image]

I don't want to try it now since I'm deploying to prod and don't want to try on test because it may mess up. I'm new to it.
Just want to make sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to "Publish" it.

But you do need to find an old book on Lotus Notes development and read about templates. Since you state that you are new to Lotus Notes, you should not be attempting anything without having at least read one book to learn the basics about something that has been around for more than 25 years. (And not just about templates!)

If you have a separate test environment, then it's pretty certain that the organization that you are working for has been using templates as part of their process for deploying applications. You should be making a local copy of the template, backing up the template, modifying the form in the local template, then using the replace design or refresh design feature to update the database in the test environment, and then you should figure out how your organization has been managing production templates and deploying the changes to production apps, and you should follow that process.

I'm being a bit vague here on purpose. I've given you the key words, but there are many ways your organization might have been managing this You need to learn the basics first, and then use what you have learned to conform to your organization's preferred practices.

Comment: And no, I'm not going to recommend a book. I wrote some of the chapters in one book, but I don't get royalties so there's no conflict of interest. It's just against StackOverflow policy to ask for recommendations for books, tools, etc. because the answers are all primarily opinion-based, and since there is such a wide range of books that you could choose, I'm going to stick with that.

Comment: Is the question on topic here at all?

Comment: Hi Richard, Thanks for you response. We have test environment, copy of the database (not replicate). Thats where I do my testing and its all good for testing now. Next step is deploying it to prod.My org practice is backing up the current form and edit it. Since Im deploying an almost new form I dont to do that practice because it will be a risk. So will it work without "Publish"? I just need to have the correct naming and it will reflect to the notes client? Thanks,

Comment: Publish is an Eclipse framework feature that is used for standalone resources in web applications. It is not applicable for design elements in an NSF file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a template is simple. Just Copy the application, set the filename to end with .ntf instead of .nsf and check the "Applicationdesign only" radio. Make sure that you have Manager access and every role in the acl.
if you have put the copy in your local notes data directory, you should be able to replace the design on the target database (File -> Application -> Replace Design) select the newly created template.

Practice first on a another test db and always have a backup.....
Additional info can be found in the designer help.